# Insert or Update multiple rows in Sql Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I need to execute a query as shown below. Columns KEY1 and KEY2 are keys that cannot be repeated. If there are keys matching, I need to perform an update VAL instead of insert. How can I do that in Sql Server?

```
INSERT INTO tableA
  ( 
      KEY1,
      KEY2,
      VAL,                      
  ) VALUES (
          -- Row A
          'datakeyA1',
          'datakeyA2',
          'somevaluetoinsertorupdate'
      ) , (
          -- Row B
          'datakeyB1',
          'datakeyB2',
          'somevaluetoinsertorupdate'
      ) , (
          -- Row C
          'datakeyC1',
          'datakeyC2',
          'somevaluetoinsertorupdate'
      );
```

I tried using MERGE, but looking at the syntax, I am not sure if it supports updating / inserting multiple rows. If anyone has encountered a similar situation in the past, could you please help out?

EDIT:

If I were using MySql, I would have just used:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
 VAL = VALUES(VAL)
```

in the query.

Comment: MERGE supports multiple rows. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Are you trying `Bulk insert / Update`

Comment: I tried `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (KEY1,KEY2,VAL)
VALUES ('datakeyA1', 'datakeyA1', 'datakeyA1'), ('datakeyB1', 'datakeyB1', 'datakeyB1');`. This seems to be an invalid syntax.

Comment: I am attempting to insert multiple rows, but looking at how to do update instead of insert when matching keys are found in the existing data. (i.e the same functionality as ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in MySql

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [table value constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd776382.aspx) as the source table to make this work with `MERGE`:

```
MERGE tableA AS t
USING (VALUES 
        ('datakeyA1', 'datakeyA2', 'somevaluetoinsertorupdate'), 
        ('datakeyB1', 'datakeyB2', 'somevaluetoinsertorupdate'),
        ('datakeyC1', 'datakeyC2', 'somevaluetoinsertorupdate')
    ) AS s (Key1, Key2, Val)
        ON s.Key1 = t.Key1
        AND s.Key2 = t.Key2
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE 
    SET    Val = s.Val
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (Key1, Key2, Val)
    VALUES (s.Key1, s.Key2, s.Val);
```

Comment: I was searching for a solution to update multiple rows in a single query, just like the INSERT INTO MyTable (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(3,4,5),[...]
and this really does it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using MERGE like this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a054/2)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA
(
    KEY1 VARCHAR(50),
    KEY2 VARCHAR(50),
    VAL VARCHAR(50)
    PRIMARY KEY (Key1, Key2)         
) 

INSERT INTO tableA
VALUES ('datakeyA1', 'datakeyA2', 'somevaluetoinsertorupdate')
```

**Query 1**:

```
MERGE  tableA AS T
USING
    (VALUES ('datakeyA1','datakeyA2','SOME NEW VALUE'), 
            ('datakeyB1','datakeyB2','somevaluetoinsertorupdate'), 
            ('datakeyC1','datakeyC2','somevaluetoinsertorupdate')) AS S(Key1, Key2, Val) 
ON (S.Key1 = T.Key1 AND S.Key2 = T.Key2)
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET T.Val = S.Val
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT (Key1, Key2, VAL) VALUES (S.Key1, S.Key2, S.Val);

SELECT *
FROM tableA
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a054/2/0)**:

```
|      KEY1 |      KEY2 |                       VAL |
|-----------|-----------|---------------------------|
| datakeyA1 | datakeyA2 |            SOME NEW VALUE |
| datakeyB1 | datakeyB2 | somevaluetoinsertorupdate |
| datakeyC1 | datakeyC2 | somevaluetoinsertorupdate |
```